# How to handle timeout error on model.predict with Heroku deployed Flask app?

Tags: heroku, flask, keras

I am trying to set up a model.predict function on my Flask app that I'd like to have deployed on Heroku. This prediction works fine locally, but when the function is called on the deployed app, it hits the 30-second timeout error.

I found a few threads that mentioned setting up a worker, which I have tried to do, but I believe I am setting up the job wrong. I have the redis set up on Heroku, and it is hitting it, but I cannot find the proper documentation to figure out why the job is not completing. It keeps entering a failed status.

/worker.py

```
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        print(f'The worker is: {worker}')
        worker.work()
```

/utils.py

```
def prepare_img(img):
    global model
    global graph
    print(f'img: {img}')
    data = {}
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    print(f'random_hex: {random_hex}')
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(img.filename)
    print(f'f_ext: {f_ext}')
    picture_fname = f'{random_hex}{f_ext}'
    print(f'picture_fname: {picture_fname}')
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/uploads', picture_fname)
    print(f'picture_path: {picture_path}')
    output_size = (299, 299)
    i = Image.open(img)
    i.thumbnail(output_size)
    i.save(picture_path)
    im = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(picture_path, target_size=output_size, grayscale=False)
    print(f'im: {im}')
    prepared_img = img_to_array(im)
    prepared_img = np.expand_dims(prepared_img, axis=0)
    prepared_img = preprocess_input(prepared_img)
    print(f'prepared_img: {prepared_img}')

    print(f'graph: {graph}')
    with graph.as_default():
        preds = model.predict(prepared_img, verbose=1)
        print(f'preds: {preds}')
        results = decode_predictions(preds)
        print(f'results: {results}')
        data['predictions'] = []
        for (imagenetID, label, prob) in results[0]:
            r = {"label": label, "probability": round(100*float(prob),2)}
            data['predictions'].append(r)
        print(f'data: {data}')
    return data, picture_fname
```

This is the output I have when I run it locally, with the prediction taking ~2 seconds at most.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUdlD.jpg

However, when the Heroku app is running the prediction the page gets through most of the steps following the print statements below, but it's getting caught on the model.predict step, and subsequently times out. Does anyone have a good example of how to use a worker job to solve this issue?

```
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710359+00:00 app[web.1]: <website.analytics.forms.ClassificationForm object at 0x7f09ab3cf710>
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710407+00:00 app[web.1]: img: <FileStorage: '36686706_227230454585436_339126893955514368_n.jpg' ('image/jpeg')>
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710491+00:00 app[web.1]: random_hex: 9ab07f8c1c3521af
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710528+00:00 app[web.1]: f_ext: .jpg
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710534+00:00 app[web.1]: picture_fname: 9ab07f8c1c3521af.jpg
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.710588+00:00 app[web.1]: picture_path: /app/website/static/uploads/9ab07f8c1c3521af.jpg
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.759655+00:00 app[web.1]: im: <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=299x299 at 0x7F09AB48B5C0>
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768021+00:00 app[web.1]: prepared_img: [[[[-0.94509804 -0.90588236 -0.8745098 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768024+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.9529412  -0.8901961  -0.8666667 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768026+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.94509804 -0.88235295 -0.85882354]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768028+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768029+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.64705884 -0.49019605 -0.56078434]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768031+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.654902   -0.4980392  -0.5686275 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768033+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6627451  -0.5058824  -0.5764706 ]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768034+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768036+00:00 app[web.1]: [[-0.9529412  -0.8901961  -0.8666667 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768037+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.9529412  -0.8901961  -0.8666667 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768039+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.9529412  -0.8745098  -0.85882354]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768041+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768043+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6784314  -0.52156866 -0.5921569 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768045+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.67058825 -0.5137255  -0.58431375]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768046+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6784314  -0.52156866 -0.5921569 ]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768048+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768049+00:00 app[web.1]: [[-0.9372549  -0.8745098  -0.8509804 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768051+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.9529412  -0.8745098  -0.85882354]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768052+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.9529412  -0.8745098  -0.85882354]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768054+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768056+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.654902   -0.4980392  -0.5686275 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768057+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6392157  -0.4823529  -0.5529412 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768059+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.62352943 -0.46666664 -0.5372549 ]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768060+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768062+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768063+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768082+00:00 app[web.1]: [[-0.7411765  -0.69411767 -0.7882353 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768088+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.70980394 -0.6627451  -0.75686276]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768089+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6862745  -0.6392157  -0.73333335]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768091+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768092+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.19215685 -0.19215685 -0.19215685]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768094+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.2235294  -0.2235294  -0.2235294 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768096+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.27058822 -0.25490195 -0.26274508]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768097+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768099+00:00 app[web.1]: [[-0.75686276 -0.70980394 -0.8039216 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768100+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.7254902  -0.6784314  -0.77254903]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768102+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6862745  -0.6392157  -0.73333335]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768103+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768105+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.16862744 -0.16862744 -0.16862744]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768106+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.19999999 -0.19999999 -0.19999999]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768108+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.24705881 -0.23137254 -0.23921567]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768109+00:00 app[web.1]:
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768110+00:00 app[web.1]: [[-0.75686276 -0.73333335 -0.81960785]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768112+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.7254902  -0.7019608  -0.7882353 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768114+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.6784314  -0.654902   -0.7411765 ]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768115+00:00 app[web.1]: ...
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768117+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.1372549  -0.1372549  -0.15294117]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768118+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.16862744 -0.16862744 -0.18431371]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768120+00:00 app[web.1]: [-0.21568626 -0.19999999 -0.2235294 ]]]]
    2019-01-31T05:04:21.768127+00:00 app[web.1]: graph: <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f0964bf4828>
    2019-01-31T05:04:51.706165+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/analytics" host=evanbeese.herokuapp.com request_id=bcbe637c-a2e5-4e82-a75b-01dee4a95c85 fwd="174.53.250.66" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30180ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

/utils.py

```
def get_model_response(img):
    print(f'get_model_response img: {img}')
    result = q.enqueue_call(func=prepare_img, args=([img]), result_ttl=600)
    while result.result is None:
        pass
    return result.result
```

/routes.py

```
        picture_file, picture_path = get_model_response(form.picture.data)
```

The app is currently deployed at http://evanbeese.herokuapp.com if seeing it helps.

Comment: Possible thing is that locally you have modern multi-core system with abundance of RAM, but it's quite usual for cloud services, that you have very limited resources on your Heroku server. I'd advise you to revise your hardware resources (and even add it to your question) and profile your model (I'd advise to make your app as simple as possible for that, removing redis-queues and others) on a Heroku server.

Comment: @Fian Thank you, and I believe what you state here is the root issue of why the app times out on the prediction. However, the solution I would like to attempt to use is setting up this worker to run the prediction, and save that result to the database. Then it can send a message to the user that their prediction has been completed or some kind of notification. Do you know if the worker operates in that way? That even if the computation exceeds the standard timeout, the worker will continue computing? I'm still trying to figure out the issue of sending to the job queue correctly.

Comment: Classic and simple approach is to return some unique id to a client app when computation is initiated, so client use this id to check whether their computation is finished and if it is -- return a result.